# How to register object in Dryloc (IOC)

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, dryioc

I decided to change IOC in my C# app. It moves from Unity to Dryloc. My problem is that I dont know how to register object in container.

In Unity it works like this:

```
AppConfiguration config = new AppConfiguration(){...}

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.Register(config);
```

but how to do it in Dryloc?

UPDATE 1:

I tried code like this:

```
 AppConfiguration config = new AppConfiguration(){...}
  var container = new DryIoc.Container();
  container.RegisterInstance(config);
```

but method RegisterInstance is not present. Container constructor name is found.
My app is using: DryIoc.dll.2.7.1\lib\net45\DryIoc.dll

UPDATE 2:

Im using VS2012, image attached:
[image: DryIOC problem]

Answer (score 2):

You use the `RegisterInstance` method:

```
container.RegisterInstance(config);
```

If you must register it to be resolved through an interface you must specify the interface as a generic argument:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
```

The first example will allow you to resolve through the class type:

```
var appConfig = container.Resolve<AppConfiguration>();
```

Please note that `RegisterInstance` (and the soon to take over `UseInstance`) method is an *extension* method.

With your updated example where you specify the namespace, this won't bring in extension methods from that namespace.

Try this:

```
using DryIoc;

...

var container = new Container();
container.RegisterInstance(....);
```

Comment: THanks for post, but I cannot find method RegisterInstance neither in Documentation nor it's not visible in VS:). You meant for DryIOC?

Comment: Yes, it works in the version I'm using. Which version of DryIoc are you using?

Comment: DryIoc.dll.2.7.1\lib\net45\DryIoc.dll  .. no such method found when I use Object Browser on it;(

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Same as you then.

Comment: Try `UseInstance` then, `RegisterInstance` is slated for removal, but it should still be present.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/src/3f0c72ae504d92cbdf353e4d086e8ea719e0f721/DryIoc/Container.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Container.cs-4314

Comment: They are static so they shoud be used like `this:DryIoc.Container.RegisterInstance `  or     `DryIoc.Container.UseInstance` right?  I cannot find it neither as static or non-static method :(

Comment: That strange that you don't see a method. Do you see the `UseInstance`?

Comment: They are extension methods, if you're doing `new DryIoc.Container` then you don't have the `using DryIoc` in the using directives.

Comment: The extension methods are defined in `DryIoc.Registrator`, not `DryIoc.Container`. If you must call them statically (because you can't or won't bring in the extension methods with a `using` directive) them you must use this class instead.

Comment: Now it works:) `DryIoc.Registrator.RegisterInstance(container, config);`

Answer (score 1):

Please use `UseInstance` method instead of `RegisterInstance` since version 2.7:

```
  AppConfiguration config = new AppConfiguration(){...}
  var container = new DryIoc.Container();
  container.UseInstance(config);
```

`UseInstance` is simpler version, which puts your instance directly into singleton or open scope, depending on what container it is called for. `RegisterInstance` which actually has its issues will be marked as `Obsolete` in next major version.

Comment: no UseInstance method in my DryIOC:). I have to reinstall it maybe.

Comment: Probably yes, or may be it is an other issue with your setup.

Comment: Ok, please install "DryIoc.dll" package instead of "DryIoc". Probably you have problem with minimal NuGet client version on VS2012